# Pass model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Im tryin to ceate a very simple blog. In my view i got this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddBlogPost", "Home")) <--Probably missing something here
{
    foreach (var item in Model.BlogPost)
     {
         @Html.LabelFor(x=>item.Title)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.Title)
         @Html.LabelFor(x=>item.Text)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>item.Text)
     }
      <input type="submit" value="Create Post"  />
}
```

With the submit-button, im hoping to pass the two values to this controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddBlogPost(BlogPost model)
        {

            BlogPost post = new BlogPost()
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                Text = model.Text,
            };

            RavenSession.Store(post);
            RavenSession.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Creating a new blogpost and saving it to the DB.
The problem is that the method receives null. Guess im missing somehting silly?

EDIT:

Im not longer passing a list of blogposts...:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddBlogPost", "Home"))
{

         @Html.LabelFor(Model.Title)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Title)
         @Html.LabelFor(Model.Text)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(Model.Text)

      <input type="submit" value="Create Post"  />
}
```

This does not seem to be the right way...

EDIT 2: These are my two class:

```
 public class ContentPage
    {
        public ContentPage()
        {
            Template = new RouteTemplate();
            ParentReference = "";
            Url = "/";


        }

        public string ParentReference { get; set; }
        public RouteTemplate Template { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool ShowInMenu { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }
    }
```

Blog-class:

```
public class BlogPost
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

To the view I pass the COntentPage, which contains an instance of the Blog-post...I cant seem to access the blogpost in the way you are describing? Sorry for not being vlear from the start.

Comment: You are posting a list while in controller you receiving a single blog post.

Comment: Any tips on how i cab solve this? Changed so that the model contains an blogPost-object instead of a list but now i cant figure out how the view should look like, please se edit.

Comment: Are you want to save single BlogPost or Multiple.?

Comment: I´d be happy with saving a single blogpost at a time for now.

Comment: I have write the method in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bind you View with the `BlogPost` class and don't use `foreach` loop. See the following code.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddBlogPost", "Home"))

    {


         @Html.LabelFor(x=>Model.Title)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.Title)
         @Html.LabelFor(x=>Model.Text)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.Text)

        <input type="submit" value="Create Post"  />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I seem to have problem accessing the Blog-post-class. Please see edit if you would.

Comment: What problem you getting in accessing the BlogPost class.?

Comment: Well this line:@Html.LabelFor(x=>Model.Title) acesses the Title-property in the COntenPage-class beacuse thats the model im passing to the view. I nedd someho to acess the Blog-object that is inside the contentpage?